# doing calculations with zrotation angles how to calculations with them when 270 degrees turns to -90 degrees?

Tags: ios, math, rotation, sprite-kit, angle

I have an object that when it rotates starts at 0 degrees pointing horizontal right, then rotates left goes to +270 degrees then changes to -90 degrees then back to zero to complete 360 rotation. (I presume this is just how spritekit works?)

How do I set this so that I could do mathematical calculations on such angles correctly? 
eg I have 2 objects that I am trying to calculate there differences in degrees to each other and set a min and max difference in angle to each other, but won't it be impossible to workout if one object flips -90 while the other is at 265degrees for a difference of 5 degrees etc?
What do I need to use/do here to successfully calculate considering 270 changes to -90 etc?

I guess I am asking how do I make my calculations start and 0 and go to 360, instead of 270 to -90 to 0?

Also my calculations are being done in radian, but I am just using degrees to display to a label so I can see it etc.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

summary :it's a modulus type operation, but modulus only works on integers and your angle may have a decimal component, so there would be typecasting and cumbersome details to store/restore any decimal component to the result..

so..
do a modulus manually..

```
CGFloat myAngle = //however you calculate that..



while (myAngle < 0.0){ 
    myAngle += 360.0;
    }
 while (myAngle > 360.0){ 
    myAngle -= 360.0;
    }
```

and if for some reason you need to take it back just change out those values to reflect the range:

```
while (myAngle < -90.0){ 
    myAngle += 360.0;
    }

while (myAngle > 270.0){ 
    myAngle -= 360.0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jef thanks for the reply the angle for my object is made via

_myobjectangle = myobject.zRotation + M_PI_2;

it is a float

How do I implement your code there? I tried it as you have it what is that actually meant to do?, your code won't adjust the values I am getting from my system will it?, but will allow me to do the calculations from 0 to 360 is that the aim of it or? Sorry don't know anything about modulus etc

Comment: the upper snippet will allow you to read and compare results by shifting whatever your getting now to 0-360, the lower shifts results back from -90 ->270 range.  I have no desire to offend, but this is rudimentary C stuff.  Have a good look at it and think about it.  If you want to write code you need to be able to understand things like this.  Also, you want to try to work in radians, I know they appear intimidating at first, but its pretty easy, pi (addressed by the constant M_PI) = 180.  2*Pi = 360..  So 90 = pi/2.0    Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks Jef yeah your last post makes it clearer I'm only new to C / programming in general I understand what is gong on with your code now, its just getting my head around how that works into what I have / trying to do that is the hard part I guess lol, I'm converting radian to degree back and forth no problem with that.